# Is the view history in Firefox 3.6.3 broken or is there an "undocumented feature"?

Tags: browser, firefox

### Firefox View History

Before Firefox 3.6.3 when I clicked `Ctrl+h` it would display my browsing history and I would be able to search it, sort it by Most Visited, Last Visited, etc.

Since 3.6.3 I have been having issues:

- Firefox does not display any entries when filtering by Most Visited or Last Visited.
- Searching does not work regardless of what keyword I use (i.e. if I type stackoverflow it won't even find it, although it's one of the most visited web sites in my history).

Is anybody experiencing similar problems? Are there any known issues that might be causing the problems that I'm seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in Firefox 3.7a4 there are no problems with the history sidebar. It appears that there's no change in functionality; perhaps your history SQLite file is corrupted?

You can inspect the database by [downloading SQLite](http://sqlite.org/), or perhaps [see what this add-on does](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11198).

Edit: the history file is located in your user profile, `places.sqlite`. [More information here.](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox_3_History_File_Format)

Comment: Deleted the places.sqlite file and everything works now. Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 1):

I don't got these problems, and i'm using 3.6.3 too.

So there must be something wrong with your installation, try a reinstall.

Comment: Reinstall it is... I hope it fixes it.

Comment: Thanks Fogh, I guess reinstall would have worked, but when I loaded my profile form a backup and it still had the same problem.

Comment: No problem, as long as you fixed your problem :)